# String into a multidimensional list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, multidimensional-array

I wanna know how to conver a string into a multidimensional list in python, the ouput i need is

```
[['K','A','R','A','L','L','O','C'], 
['G','N','T','E','B','M','A','I'], 
['B','H','E','O','C','P','F','M'], 
['R','U','N','E','O','F','U','M'], 
['A','W','G','K','D','U','R','A'], 
['V','D','R','E','C','A','Z','S'], 
['E','M','J','A','L','O','T','S'], 
['O','X','V','A','C','U','N','U']]
```

But i just know how to convert in this form

```
[['KARALLOC'], ['GNTEBMAI'], ['BHEOCPFM'], ['RUNEOFUM'], ['AWGKDURA'], ['VDRECAZS'], ['EMJALOTS'], ['OXVACUNU']]
```

My code is this:

```
from textwrap import wrap

def words(letters):
    gridLetters = wrap(letters,8)

    separarParabras = [gridLetters[i*1:i*1+1] for i in range(8)]

    return separarParabras

print(words('KARALLOCGNTEBMAIBHEOCPFMRUNEOFUMAWGKDURAVDRECAZSEMJALOTSOXVACUNU'))
```

Comment: Can you think of how to split the letters apart for a single row? Then just do that for all the rows. What is the difficulty?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one liner that does it (although not a fan of this solution)
`[list(x) for x in [word[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(word), 8)]]`

A better one liner (as @chris mentionned):
`[list(w[i:i+8]) for i in range(0, len(w), 8)]`

I would split it into two:

```
text = 'KARALLOCGNTEBMAIBHEOCPFMRUNEOFUMAWGKDURAVDRECAZSEMJALOTSOXVACUNU'
n = 8
words = [text[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(text), n)]
grid_letters = [list(w) for w in words]
```

Output:

```
[['K', 'A', 'R', 'A', 'L', 'L', 'O', 'C'], 
['G', 'N', 'T', 'E', 'B', 'M', 'A', 'I'], 
['B', 'H', 'E', 'O', 'C', 'P', 'F', 'M'], 
['R', 'U', 'N', 'E', 'O', 'F', 'U', 'M'], 
['A', 'W', 'G', 'K', 'D', 'U', 'R', 'A'], 
['V', 'D', 'R', 'E', 'C', 'A', 'Z', 'S'], 
['E', 'M', 'J', 'A', 'L', 'O', 'T', 'S'], 
['O', 'X', 'V', 'A', 'C', 'U', 'N', 'U']]
```

Comment: You can shorten it by directly making a `list`: `[list(w[i:i+8]) for i in range(0, len(w), 8)]`. But nice code anyway +1

Comment: True that ^^ will add it

Answer (score 1):

```
from textwrap import wrap

def words(letters):
    gridLetters = wrap(letters,8)
    separarParabras = [[char for char in gridLetters[i]] for i in range(8)]

    return separarParabras

print(words('KARALLOCGNTEBMAIBHEOCPFMRUNEOFUMAWGKDURAVDRECAZSEMJALOTSOXVACUNU'))
```

The trick was to have a nested list comprehension, where you pick a word from gridLetters using `gridLetters[i]` and iterate through the characters in it

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
def words(s, size):
    return [[ch for ch in s[i*size:(i + 1)*size]]  for i in range(8)]

for e in words('KARALLOCGNTEBMAIBHEOCPFMRUNEOFUMAWGKDURAVDRECAZSEMJALOTSOXVACUNU', 8):
    print(e)
```

Output

```
['K', 'A', 'R', 'A', 'L', 'L', 'O', 'C']
['G', 'N', 'T', 'E', 'B', 'M', 'A', 'I']
['B', 'H', 'E', 'O', 'C', 'P', 'F', 'M']
['R', 'U', 'N', 'E', 'O', 'F', 'U', 'M']
['A', 'W', 'G', 'K', 'D', 'U', 'R', 'A']
['V', 'D', 'R', 'E', 'C', 'A', 'Z', 'S']
['E', 'M', 'J', 'A', 'L', 'O', 'T', 'S']
['O', 'X', 'V', 'A', 'C', 'U', 'N', 'U']
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import textwrap    
a = 'KARALLOCGNTEBMAIBHEOCPFMRUNEOFUMAWGKDURAVDRECAZSEMJALOTSOXVACUNU'
a = textwrap.wrap(a, 8)
res = list(map(lambda x: list(x), a))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[['K', 'A', 'R', 'A', 'L', 'L', 'O', 'C'],
 ['G', 'N', 'T', 'E', 'B', 'M', 'A', 'I'],
 ['B', 'H', 'E', 'O', 'C', 'P', 'F', 'M'],
 ['R', 'U', 'N', 'E', 'O', 'F', 'U', 'M'],
 ['A', 'W', 'G', 'K', 'D', 'U', 'R', 'A'],
 ['V', 'D', 'R', 'E', 'C', 'A', 'Z', 'S'],
 ['E', 'M', 'J', 'A', 'L', 'O', 'T', 'S'],
 ['O', 'X', 'V', 'A', 'C', 'U', 'N', 'U']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firs find string, then split it into list, and then use list comprehension

Try this one liner:

```
li = [['KARALLOC'], ['GNTEBMAI'], ['BHEOCPFM'], ['RUNEOFUM'], ['AWGKDURA'], ['VDRECAZS'], ['EMJALOTS'], ['OXVACUNU']]


li = [list(item) for l in li for item in l]
print(li)
```